# Shannon Capacity Formula in AMPL

Tags: optimization, cplex, ampl, capacity

I want to use Shannon Capacity forumula as one of my constraint in the minimization problem. I am not sure how can I use it as AMPL doesnot support log2.

In simple form its here as: C = B * log2(1+ S/N)
Please guide.

[image: Shannon Cappacity Formula]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we know log2(x)=ln(x)/log(2)
We can apply in APML as AMPL supports natural logrithm.

Comment: Assuming X is your decision variable and the other terms are constants, that is a good approach. If B1 and C1 were the only variables, a good option would be to apply an exponential transform to both sides (f -> 2^f) and get rid of the logarithms altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use extended function libraries provided for AMPL at https://ampl.com/resources/extended-function-library/ by loading this package you can use log(x) as well :

```
 gsl_sf_log(x)
```